# Is there a way to cause a UI input box to pop up at specified intervals regardless of the page you're on using Apps Scipt?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to prompt the user to enter data into a workbook at regular intervals using a UI input box and Google Apps Script. Something like this but with the timer added:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var timer = Browser.inputBox('New Data', 'How many minutes?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  ss.appendRow([timer]);
}
```

Is there a way to force the spreadsheet window to be the active window when the timer goes off or somehow alert the user to enter data if they've navigated away from the page? TIA!!!

Comment: Have you looked at [Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String,String,Number))?

Comment: Hi ! Unfortunately you cannot trigger [Browser.inputBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputboxprompt,-buttons) or [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) with [time based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). Why you do want to launch the input box several times after a period of time? How many times would you need this input box to trigger?

Comment: @Cooper that looks really neat but doesn't appear to allow for input.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Initially I'd like to collect data on what task I'm engaged in when the alert goes off (at regular intervals for a specific period of time...say every 5 minutes for 30 minutes for example). I'm a behavior analyst by trade and I'm working on ideas to help with on-task behavior for distance learners.

Comment: Are you going to have someone sitting there watching the spreadsheet? Just waiting for this message.  I think I'd prefer sending an email or text message to their phone and giving them a webapp to enter the data.

Comment: @Cooper the idea is to catch the activity in that exact moment. At it's most basic, I'd love to have a window that pops up and asks if I'm on or off task and have the feedback sent to a workbook. That's why I was looking for something that would pop up regardless of what page I was on. I'd like to go back later and look at the workbook to see what percentage of intervals I was on task. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well dialogs are not tied to sheets or tabs as some call them.  So the dialog will appear above the spreadsheet no matter what page you are on.   And you could also use the sidebar to accomplish same thing

Comment: @Cooper what about if I’m on an entirely different page (viewing google search results, for example). Would a Chrome extension allow for that kind of persistence?

Comment: I've never written any chrome extension.  I don't think gas has any control over what browswer window your own.  Your code is about spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

From the information you have provided and your requirements (pop up a dialog not only when you are on the Spreadsheet but also on any page of the browser) I think your best option would be to create or use a Chrome extension. If you want to pass the data received in this extension into a specific Spreadsheet to log the user's activity then you want to use [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).

The problems using simply [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for this case scenario are the following:

- [Time based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) cannot trigger an UI element such as [Browser.inputBox()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputboxtitle,-prompt,-buttons) or [getUi](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- An UI dialog in the Spreadsheet stops the execution of the script until it is dismissed. This will lead that if your user forgets to add the information and close the dialog the script will stop, missing also the next time turns.
- The user would need to have the Spreadsheet tab opened as the script only controls what is going on the Spreadsheet and not in the browser. As you want to track the behaviour no matter in which tab the user is in, I believe that it would be best experience for the user to simply have a Chrome extension that does that job.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still working through which tools are best suited for each situation and your reply makes a lot of sense. It looks like Chrome Extensions use the same tools I've been studying (HTML, CSS, JS) so that's perfect. Thank you again!